# Cannot access a global variable in my callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scope

So I'm retrieving a bunch of JSON from the twitch API and trying to append some stuff to a div.

HTML:

```
<div id="streamers" class="streamers">

</div>
```

JS:

```
const channels = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
const streamers = document.getElementById("streamers");
for(let i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {
  let url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + channels[i] + "?client_id=blahblahblahblah&callback=?";

  function callback(data) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = channels[i];
    console.log(li);
    streamers.appendChild(li);
  } 

  $.getJSON(url, callback);
}
```

However I am receiving a `Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null` error. I tried `console.log(streamers)` however this returns null. Accessing `channels` is no problem and this is also a global variable.

I can easily fix the problem by putting the `streamers` const into the callback function. But what I want to know is why I can't access it globally? If I am correct, variables that are undefined in a function will search outside until it finds a match.

Thanks,
James.

Comment: Seems to be hoisting issue. Try once with Anonymous method  `$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = channels[i];
    console.log(li);
    streamers.appendChild(li);
  });`

Comment: As a test, If you try to appendChild on the line below where streamers is defined,(ie outside the function) does that work?

Comment: Have you made sure that `document.getElementById('streamers')` is being executed **after** element with id `streamers` has been added to DOM ?

Comment: @BarryThomas It doesn't... Strange

Comment: @JamesBarrett - Might be what Teqchiqe mentioned above so. possibly placing the const streamers in a document.ready function will resolve

Comment: @BarryThomas Ugh, just found out my script tag wasn't even below the closing body tag. Problem solved. D'oh!!

Comment: Its always the small things. :)

Answer (score 0):

based on following definition
"let and const declarations define variables that are scoped to the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment."

```
for(let i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) { // it enter's to a new scope
```